# Trigger shipping email manually using order id in magento2

Tags: magento2, shipping

I want to trigger shipping email manually , while hitting file i tried below but mail is not triggered please tell me any option available to sent email?

```
$convertOrder = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
        $shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($order);

        // Loop through order items
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
            // Check if order item has qty to ship or is virtual
            if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                continue;
            }
            $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
            // Create shipment item with qty
            $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);
            // Add shipment item to shipment
            $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
        }
        $shipment->register();
        $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
        try {
            // Save created shipment and order
            $shipment->save();
            $shipment->getOrder()->save();
            // Send email
                $objectManager->create('Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier')
                ->notify($shipment);
echo "mail success";
                $shipment->save();

        }
```

Comment: try to put your complete code in try.....catch block, So if any error throught it will show.

Comment: Is there any option available in API?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Area code is not set in my exception

Comment: have you try run code from file which places in magento root?

Comment: Yes magento root @DhirenVasoya

Comment: I posted answer for your above things, If it show error like "area code is not set". please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69904/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-jeeva-chezhiyan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your run above code show from magento root and it show error like this : `Area code is not set`
then used this code

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

    $convertOrder = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
    $shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($order);

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
        // Check if order item has qty to ship or is virtual
        if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
             continue;
        }
        $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
        // Create shipment item with qty
        $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);
        // Add shipment item to shipment
        $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
      }
      $shipment->register();
      $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
            try {
                // Save created shipment and order
                $shipment->save();
                $shipment->getOrder()->save();
                // Send email
                    $objectManager->create('Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier')
                    ->notify($shipment);
    echo "mail success";
                    $shipment->save();

            }
```

Comment: Few mins @Dhiren i'll try this

Comment: ok try and let me know.

Comment: If above code help you, please accept it, show it will help other in community as well.